# AER dispersiontest() contradict negative binomial dispersion in R

Tags: r, statistics, poisson

I am analyzing the Poisson regression of a data count. Poisson requires that the variance and mean is equal, so I am checking the dispersion to ensure this. For the dispersion I am using two methods:

- dispersiontest() by AER package.
- check the dispersion modeling as a negative binomial with (glm.nb)

```
> pm <- glm(myCounts ~ campaign, d, family = poisson)
> summary(pm)

Call:
glm(formula = myCounts ~ campaign, family = poisson, data = d)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-4.074  -1.599  -0.251   1.636   6.399  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.955870   0.032174  154.03   <2e-16 ***
campaign    -0.025879   0.001716  -15.08   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 428.04  on 35  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 195.81  on 34  degrees of freedom
AIC: 426.37

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> dispersiontest(pm)

    Overdispersion test

data:  pm
z = 3.1933, p-value = 0.0007032
alternative hypothesis: true dispersion is greater than 1
sample estimates:
dispersion 
   5.53987 

> # Calculate dispersion with Negative Binomial
> nb_reg <- glm.nb(myCounts ~ campaign, data=d)
> summary.glm(nb_reg)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = myCounts ~ campaign, data = d, init.theta = 22.0750109, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9235  -0.7083  -0.1776   0.6707   2.4495  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.914728   0.082327  59.697  < 2e-16 ***
campaign    -0.023471   0.003965  -5.919  1.1e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(22.075) family taken to be 1.069362)

    Null deviance: 76.887  on 35  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 35.534  on 34  degrees of freedom
AIC: 325.76

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
```

As you can see, NB provides a 1.069362 dispersion. However, dispersiontest() results on 5.5 with clear overdispersion. If I am not wrong AER is not a parametric test, so we can only know if there is a over/under-dispersion or not. Nevertheless, both methods contradict.

Do somebody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In glm.nb(), the variance is parameterized as +^2/ where  is your mean (See more at [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/what-is-theta-in-a-negative-binomial-regression-fitted-with-r)) and  is theta, whereas in a poisson it is `ϕ *`  where ϕ is the dispersion 5.53987 you see.

In negative binomial, the dispersion `1.069362` will not make sense, you need to look at theta inside the Negative Binomial(), which in your case is 22.075. I don't have your data, but using your intercept as a rough estimate of the mean:

```
mu = exp(4.914728)
theta = 22.0750109
variance = mu + (mu^2)/theta
variance
977.6339
variance / mu
[1] 7.173598
```

Which gives you something similar to the dispersion you. You should note that the dispersion you have is estimated from the full model, whereas I simply guessed one from your intercept.

Bottom line is the results don't disagree. You can use the negative binomial to model your data.

Below is an example that will illustrate the above relation. We simulate overdispersed data using negative binomial (that's the easiest):

```
y = c(rnbinom(100,mu=100,size=22),rnbinom(100,mu=200,size=22))
x = rep(0:1,each=100)

AER::dispersiontest(glm(y~x,family=poisson))

    Overdispersion test

data:  glm(y ~ x, family = poisson)
z = 8.0606, p-value = 3.795e-16
alternative hypothesis: true dispersion is greater than 1
sample estimates:
dispersion 
  8.200214
```

Roughly, this is derived by dividing the variance in each group over mean in each group:

```
mean(tapply(y,x,var)/tapply(y,x,mean))
[1] 8.283044
```

And you can see the dispersion is showing 1, when in fact your data is overdispered:

```
    summary(MASS::glm.nb(y~x))

Call:
MASS::glm.nb(formula = y ~ x, init.theta = 21.5193965, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.0413  -0.6999  -0.1275   0.5800   2.4774  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.66551    0.02364  197.36   <2e-16 ***
x            0.66682    0.03274   20.37   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(21.5194) family taken to be 1)
```

Comment: I think that the  approximation of the dispersion by checking the negbin distribution is valid. You can test a large variance of generated poisson distributions and the reported dispersion  is always close to 1. 
```
n=30
mu=10
x=seq(n)
y=rpois(n,mu)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
nb = glm.nb(y~x, data=df)
summary.glm(nb)
```
The dispersion is around 1.01. If you try this for really large n, n=200000-300000, it is oscilating around 1.0 with a delta about 1E-3. My understanding of AER is that it reports the z-value assuming that dispersion would be normal-distributed -> non-parameteric.

Comment: @jentila, everything you do here is parametric. It has nothing to do with sample size. i strongly recommend reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf

Comment: regarding the test, read the source code of https://github.com/cran/AER/blob/master/R/dispersiontest.R ; it calculates the p-value using a pnorm, which is parametric.

Comment: instead of checking dispersion with NB, if we checked it with quasipoisson? is this a good test? I have checked and results are quite similar to dispersiontest(). I want to have at least two methods for assurance.

Comment: you can use that. My point is.. if you need to model the data, NB might be better

Answer (score 0):

I think everything worked well, your test says that your data are overdispersed.
I fact, p<0.05 means that you fail to accept the null hypothesis, and your hypotheses are:

H0: data are not oberdispersed
H1: data are overdispersed

In your case the probability that data are not overdispersed is lower than 0.05. So, you "can say" that your data are overdispersed, which is coherent with your negative binomial output.